# Upgrading from boost 1.38 to 1.39 causes my call to boost::algorithm::split not to compile

Tags: c++, boost

I was using Boost 1.38, and I just upgraded to 1.39. Upgrading broke the following bit of code:

```
std::vector<std::wstring> consoleParser::loadStringsFromFile(const std::wstring &fileName)
{
    std::vector<std::wstring> files;
    std::wstring fileString(loadFileAsString(fileName));
    boost::algorithm::split(files, fileString, boost::is_any_of(L"\r\n'\"")); //Error on this line
    return files;
}
```

Any ideas on what's causing the failure? My compiler helpfully emits the following:

```
c:\boost\boost\utility\addressof.hpp(30) : error C2220: warning treated as error - no 'object' file generated
        c:\boost\boost\utility\addressof.hpp(56) : see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::detail::addr_impl_ref<T>' being compiled
        with
        [
            T=boost::algorithm::detail::token_finderF<boost::algorithm::detail::is_any_ofF<wchar_t>>
        ]
        c:\boost\boost\function\function_template.hpp(600) : see reference to function template instantiation 'T *boost::addressof<FunctionObj>(T &)' being compiled
        with
        [
            T=boost::algorithm::detail::token_finderF<boost::algorithm::detail::is_any_ofF<wchar_t>>,
            FunctionObj=boost::algorithm::detail::token_finderF<boost::algorithm::detail::is_any_ofF<wchar_t>>
        ]
        c:\boost\boost\function\function_template.hpp(491) : see reference to function template instantiation 'bool boost::detail::function::basic_vtable2<R,T0,T1>::assign_to<F>(FunctionObj,boost::detail::function::function_buffer &,boost::detail::function::function_obj_tag)' being compiled
        with
        [
            R=boost::iterator_range<std::_String_iterator<wchar_t,std::char_traits<wchar_t>,std::allocator<wchar_t>>>,
            T0=std::_String_iterator<wchar_t,std::char_traits<wchar_t>,std::allocator<wchar_t>>,
            T1=std::_String_iterator<wchar_t,std::char_traits<wchar_t>,std::allocator<wchar_t>>,
            F=boost::algorithm::detail::token_finderF<boost::algorithm::detail::is_any_ofF<wchar_t>>,
            FunctionObj=boost::algorithm::detail::token_finderF<boost::algorithm::detail::is_any_ofF<wchar_t>>
        ]
        c:\boost\boost\function\function_template.hpp(906) : see reference to function template instantiation 'bool boost::detail::function::basic_vtable2<R,T0,T1>::assign_to<Functor>(F,boost::detail::function::function_buffer &)' being compiled
        with
        [
            R=boost::iterator_range<std::_String_iterator<wchar_t,std::char_traits<wchar_t>,std::allocator<wchar_t>>>,
            T0=std::_String_iterator<wchar_t,std::char_traits<wchar_t>,std::allocator<wchar_t>>,
            T1=std::_String_iterator<wchar_t,std::char_traits<wchar_t>,std::allocator<wchar_t>>,
            Functor=boost::algorithm::detail::token_finderF<boost::algorithm::detail::is_any_ofF<wchar_t>>,
            F=boost::algorithm::detail::token_finderF<boost::algorithm::detail::is_any_ofF<wchar_t>>
        ]
        c:\boost\boost\function\function_template.hpp(720) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void boost::function2<R,T0,T1>::assign_to<Functor>(Functor)' being compiled
        with
        [
            R=boost::iterator_range<std::_String_iterator<wchar_t,std::char_traits<wchar_t>,std::allocator<wchar_t>>>,
            T0=std::_String_iterator<wchar_t,std::char_traits<wchar_t>,std::allocator<wchar_t>>,
            T1=std::_String_iterator<wchar_t,std::char_traits<wchar_t>,std::allocator<wchar_t>>,
            Functor=boost::algorithm::detail::token_finderF<boost::algorithm::detail::is_any_ofF<wchar_t>>
        ]
        c:\boost\boost\algorithm\string\detail\find_iterator.hpp(51) : see reference to function template instantiation 'boost::function2<R,T0,T1>::function2<FinderT>(Functor,int)' being compiled
        with
        [
            R=boost::iterator_range<std::_String_iterator<wchar_t,std::char_traits<wchar_t>,std::allocator<wchar_t>>>,
            T0=std::_String_iterator<wchar_t,std::char_traits<wchar_t>,std::allocator<wchar_t>>,
            T1=std::_String_iterator<wchar_t,std::char_traits<wchar_t>,std::allocator<wchar_t>>,
            FinderT=boost::algorithm::detail::token_finderF<boost::algorithm::detail::is_any_ofF<wchar_t>>,
            Functor=boost::algorithm::detail::token_finderF<boost::algorithm::detail::is_any_ofF<wchar_t>>
        ]
        c:\boost\boost\algorithm\string\find_iterator.hpp(261) : see reference to function template instantiation 'boost::algorithm::detail::find_iterator_base<IteratorT>::find_iterator_base<FinderT>(FinderT,int)' being compiled
        with
        [
            IteratorT=input_iterator_type,
            FinderT=boost::algorithm::detail::token_finderF<boost::algorithm::detail::is_any_ofF<wchar_t>>
        ]
        c:\boost\boost\algorithm\string\iter_find.hpp(167) : see reference to function template instantiation 'boost::algorithm::split_iterator<IteratorT>::split_iterator<FinderT>(IteratorT,IteratorT,FinderT)' being compiled
        with
        [
            IteratorT=input_iterator_type,
            FinderT=boost::algorithm::detail::token_finderF<boost::algorithm::detail::is_any_ofF<wchar_t>>
        ]
        c:\boost\boost\algorithm\string\split.hpp(149) : see reference to function template instantiation 'SequenceSequenceT &boost::algorithm::iter_split<SequenceSequenceT,RangeT,boost::algorithm::detail::token_finderF<PredicateT>>(SequenceSequenceT &,RangeT &,FinderT)' being compiled
        with
        [
            SequenceSequenceT=std::vector<std::wstring>,
            RangeT=std::wstring,
            PredicateT=boost::algorithm::detail::is_any_ofF<wchar_t>,
            FinderT=boost::algorithm::detail::token_finderF<boost::algorithm::detail::is_any_ofF<wchar_t>>
        ]
        c:\documents and settings\user\my documents\visual studio 2008\projects\pevfind\pevfind\consoleparser.cpp(1529) : see reference to function template instantiation 'SequenceSequenceT &boost::algorithm::split<std::vector<_Ty>,std::wstring,boost::algorithm::detail::is_any_ofF<CharT>>(SequenceSequenceT &,RangeT &,PredicateT,boost::algorithm::token_compress_mode_type)' being compiled
        with
        [
            SequenceSequenceT=std::vector<std::wstring>,
            _Ty=std::wstring,
            CharT=wchar_t,
            RangeT=std::wstring,
            PredicateT=boost::algorithm::detail::is_any_ofF<wchar_t>
        ]
c:\boost\boost\utility\addressof.hpp(30) : warning C4512: 'boost::detail::addr_impl_ref<T>' : assignment operator could not be generated
        with
        [
            T=boost::algorithm::detail::token_finderF<boost::algorithm::detail::is_any_ofF<wchar_t>>
        ]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your compile failed because there's a new warning being emitted (`boost::detail::addr_impl_ref<T>' : assignment operator could not be generated`), and your settings are set to treat warnings as errors. Judging from [this](http://www.nabble.com/-utility--foreach--1.39.0--warning-C4512-td23446419.html) and [this](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/2993), it's indeed an issue with Boost 1.39.0 and VS2008.

The latter link provides a patch that fixes the issue. It should be fixed in Boost 1.40.0.

The alternative would be to disable the "treat warnings as errors" flag temporarily.

Answer (score 1):

If I switch to warning level 4 and set treat warnings as errors mine breaks too.
Try changing those settings.

Answer (score 0):

I really don't like "treat warnings as errors" for this kind of reason, but you can just do:

```
#pragma warning (disable:4512)
```

above any #include line for addressof.hpp.